# "There is no such file sbjson.h" chimpkit

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to subscribe a maillist. I need to use mailchimp API for it. I know chimpkit2 is the wrapper for objective-c. I downloaded a sample project using this link: https://github.com/mailchimp/chimpkit2 and tried to run it but it did not work. I gives me "There is no such file sbjson.h" error. I tried to include sbjson framework to my project but it gave other errors this time.

How can I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may have forgotten to import the json-framework dependency. From the Chimpkit docs:

> cd Lib/ChimpKit
>
> git submodule init
>
> git submodule update